# mySQL: SUM electrical usage data by peak use, off peak use and total use GROUP BY site and day

Tags: mysql, date, sum, subquery, group

I have a mySQL table with 5 or 15 minute interval electrical usage data. I would like to sum each site's yesterday usage and summarise 'off peak', 'peak' and Total use for each site.

Desired Output:

| NMI | SiteName | Date | OffPeak Use | Peak Use | Total |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 203020212 | Site1 | 20/2/24 | 200 | 150 | 350 |
| 203020214 | Site2 | 20/2/24 | 600 | 5 | 605 |
| 203020216 | Site3 | 20/2/24 | 800 | 20 | 820 |

**NMIList Table Data:**

```
"nmi","SiteName"
"2001767790","Pivot 2"
"2002172225","Dairy"
"2002173221","Pivot 1"
```

`**Elecdata Table Data:**
"nmi","timestamp","interval_min","rate","kWh_con","kVArh_con","kWh_ex","kVArh_ex"
"2001767790","2024-02-19 23:55:00","5","Off-Peak","5.36","3.03","0","0"
"2002172225","2024-02-19 23:55:00","5","Off-Peak","1.61","0","0","0.02"
"2001767790","2024-02-19 23:50:00","5","Off-Peak","5.38","3.04","0","0"
"2002172225","2024-02-19 23:50:00","5","Off-Peak","1.61","0","0","0.02"
"2001767790","2024-02-19 23:45:00","5","Off-Peak","5.38","3.05","0","0"
"2002172225","2024-02-19 23:45:00","5","Off-Peak","1.62","0","0","0.01"
"2002173221","2024-02-19 23:45:00","15","Off-Peak","20.408","10.976","0","0"
"2001767790","2024-02-19 23:40:00","5","Off-Peak","5.35","3.07","0","0"
"2002172225","2024-02-19 23:40:00","5","Off-Peak","1.64","0","0","0.02"
"2001767790","2024-02-19 23:35:00","5","Off-Peak","5.36","3.11","0","0"
"2002172225","2024-02-19 23:35:00","5","Off-Peak","1.65","0.02","0","0.02"
"2001767790","2024-02-19 23:30:00","5","Off-Peak","5.36","3.11","0","0"
"2002172225","2024-02-19 23:30:00","5","Off-Peak","1.64","0","0","0.01"
"2002173221","2024-02-19 23:30:00","15","Off-Peak","20.392","11.104","0","0"
"2001767790","2024-02-19 23:25:00","5","Off-Peak","5.35","3.09","0","0"
"2002172225","2024-02-19 23:25:00","5","Off-Peak","1.64","0","0","0.02"
"2001767790","2024-02-19 23:20:00","5","Off-Peak","5.36","3.11","0","0"
"2002172225","2024-02-19 23:20:00","5","Off-Peak","1.64","0","0","0.02"
"2001767790","2024-02-19 23:15:00","5","Off-Peak","5.36","3.1","0","0"
"2002172225","2024-02-19 23:15:00","5","Off-Peak","1.64","0","0","0.02"
"2002173221","2024-02-19 23:15:00","15","Off-Peak","20.536","11.208","0","0"
"2001767790","2024-02-19 23:10:00","5","Off-Peak","5.35","3.09","0","0"
"2002172225","2024-02-19 23:10:00","5","Off-Peak","1.64","0","0","0.01"
"2001767790","2024-02-19 23:05:00","5","Off-Peak","5.36","3.1","0","0"
"2002172225","2024-02-19 23:05:00","5","Off-Peak","1.68","0.02","0","0.01"
"2001767790","2024-02-19 23:00:00","5","Off-Peak","5.36","3.1","0","0"
"2002172225","2024-02-19 23:00:00","5","Off-Peak","1.68","0","0","0"
"2002173221","2024-02-19 23:00:00","15","Off-Peak","20.568","11.2","0","0"
"2001767790","2024-02-19 22:55:00","5","Off-Peak","5.36","3.09","0","0"
"2002172225","2024-02-19 22:55:00","5","Off-Peak","1.68","0.01","0","0"
"2001767790","2024-02-19 22:50:00","5","Off-Peak","5.36","3.09","0","0"
"2002172225","2024-02-19 22:50:00","5","Off-Peak","1.68","0","0","0"
"2001767790","2024-02-19 22:45:00","5","Off-Peak","5.37","3.08","0","0"
"2002172225","2024-02-19 22:45:00","5","Off-Peak","1.67","0.01","0","0"
"2002173221","2024-02-19 22:45:00","15","Off-Peak","20.68","11.208","0","0"
"2001767790","2024-02-19 22:40:00","5","Off-Peak","5.35","3.05","0","0"
"2002172225","2024-02-19 22:40:00","5","Off-Peak","1.66","0","0","0"
"2001767790","2024-02-19 22:35:00","5","Off-Peak","5.37","3.06","0","0"
"2002172225","2024-02-19 22:35:00","5","Off-Peak","1.68","0.02","0","0"
"2001767790","2024-02-19 22:30:00","5","Off-Peak","5.35","3.05","0","0"
"2002172225","2024-02-19 22:30:00","5","Off-Peak","1.67","0.01","0","0"
"2002173221","2024-02-19 22:30:00","15","Off-Peak","20.688","11.16","0","0"
"2001767790","2024-02-19 22:25:00","5","Off-Peak","5.35","3.05","0","0"
"2002172225","2024-02-19 22:25:00","5","Off-Peak","1.35","0","0","0"
"2001767790","2024-02-19 22:20:00","5","Off-Peak","5.37","3.05","0","0"
"2002172225","2024-02-19 22:20:00","5","Off-Peak","1.35","0","0","0"
"2001767790","2024-02-19 22:15:00","5","Off-Peak","5.36","3.04","0","0"
"2002172225","2024-02-19 22:15:00","5","Off-Peak","0.37","0.01","0","0.01"
"2002173221","2024-02-19 22:15:00","15","Off-Peak","20.656","11.152","0","0"
"2001767790","2024-02-19 22:10:00","5","Off-Peak","5.37","3.04","0","0"
"2002172225","2024-02-19 22:10:00","5","Off-Peak","0.08","0","0","0.02"
"2001767790","2024-02-19 22:05:00","5","Off-Peak","5.37","3.04","0","0"
"2002172225","2024-02-19 22:05:00","5","Off-Peak","0.09","0","0","0.02"
"2001767790","2024-02-19 22:00:00","5","Off-Peak","5.15","2.97","0","0"
"2002172225","2024-02-19 22:00:00","5","Off-Peak","0.99","0.87","0","0"
"2002173221","2024-02-19 22:00:00","15","Off-Peak","20.296","10.88","0","0"
"2001767790","2024-02-19 21:55:00","5","Peak","0","0","0","0"
"2002172225","2024-02-19 21:55:00","5","Peak","0.77","0.77","0","0.01"
"2001767790","2024-02-19 21:50:00","5","Peak","0","0","0","0"
"2002172225","2024-02-19 21:50:00","5","Peak","0.08","0","0","0.02"
"2001767790","2024-02-19 21:45:00","5","Peak","0","0","0","0"
"2002172225","2024-02-19 21:45:00","5","Peak","0.08","0","0","0.02"
"2002173221","2024-02-19 21:45:00","15","Peak","0.424","0.392","0","0"
"2001767790","2024-02-19 21:40:00","5","Peak","0","0","0","0"
"2002172225","2024-02-19 21:40:00","5","Peak","0.09","0","0","0.02"
"2001767790","2024-02-19 21:35:00","5","Peak","0","0","0","0"
"2002172225","2024-02-19 21:35:00","5","Peak","0.09","0","0","0.01"
"2001767790","2024-02-19 21:30:00","5","Peak","0","0","0","0"
"2002172225","2024-02-19 21:30:00","5","Peak","0.09","0.01","0","0.02"
"2002173221","2024-02-19 21:30:00","15","Peak","0.128","0.08","0","0"
"2001767790","2024-02-19 21:25:00","5","Peak","0","0","0","0"
"2002172225","2024-02-19 21:25:00","5","Peak","0.08","0","0","0.01"
"2001767790","2024-02-19 21:20:00","5","Peak","0","0","0","0"
"2002172225","2024-02-19 21:20:00","5","Peak","0.09","0","0","0.02"
"2001767790","2024-02-19 21:15:00","5","Peak","0","0","0","0"
"2002172225","2024-02-19 21:15:00","5","Peak","0.08","0.01","0","0.02"
"2002173221","2024-02-19 21:15:00","15","Peak","0.128","0.08","0","0"
"2001767790","2024-02-19 21:10:00","5","Peak","0","0","0","0"
"2002172225","2024-02-19 21:10:00","5","Peak","0.09","0","0","0.01"
"2001767790","2024-02-19 21:05:00","5","Peak","0","0","0","0"
"2002172225","2024-02-19 21:05:00","5","Peak","0.09","0","0","0.02"
"2001767790","2024-02-19 21:00:00","5","Peak","0","0","0","0"
"2002172225","2024-02-19 21:00:00","5","Peak","0.11","0.01","0","0.01"
"2002173221","2024-02-19 21:00:00","15","Peak","0.168","0.112","0","0"
"2001767790","2024-02-19 20:55:00","5","Peak","0","0","0","0"
"2002172225","2024-02-19 20:55:00","5","Peak","0.08","0","0","0.02"
"2001767790","2024-02-19 20:50:00","5","Peak","0","0","0","0"
"2002172225","2024-02-19 20:50:00","5","Peak","0.09","0.01","0","0.01"
"2001767790","2024-02-19 20:45:00","5","Peak","0","0","0","0"
"2002172225","2024-02-19 20:45:00","5","Peak","0.08","0","0","0.01"
"2002173221","2024-02-19 20:45:00","15","Peak","0.16","0.104","0","0"
"2001767790","2024-02-19 20:40:00","5","Peak","0","0","0","0"
"2002172225","2024-02-19 20:40:00","5","Peak","0.09","0","0","0.02"
"2001767790","2024-02-19 20:35:00","5","Peak","0","0","0","0"
"2002172225","2024-02-19 20:35:00","5","Peak","0.09","0","0","0.01"
"2001767790","2024-02-19 20:30:00","5","Peak","0","0","0","0"
"2002172225","2024-02-19 20:30:00","5","Peak","0.08","0.01","0","0.02"
"2002173221","2024-02-19 20:30:00","15","Peak","0.16","0.104","0","0"
"2001767790","2024-02-19 20:25:00","5","Peak","0","0","0","0"
"2002172225","2024-02-19 20:25:00","5","Peak","0.1","0.01","0","0.01"
"2001767790","2024-02-19 20:20:00","5","Peak","0","0","0","0"
"2002172225","2024-02-19 20:20:00","5","Peak","0.09","0","0","0.01"
"2001767790","2024-02-19 20:15:00","5","Peak","0","0","0","0"
"2002172225","2024-02-19 20:15:00","5","Peak","0.09","0","0","0.02"
"2002173221","2024-02-19 20:15:00","15","Peak","0.128","0.088","0","0"
"2001767790","2024-02-19 20:10:00","5","Peak","0","0","0","0"
"2002172225","2024-02-19 20:10:00","5","Peak","0.08","0.01","0","0.01"
"2001767790","2024-02-19 20:05:00","5","Peak","0","0","0","0"
"2002172225","2024-02-19 20:05:00","5","Peak","0.08","0","0","0.02"
"2001767790","2024-02-19 20:00:00","5","Peak","0","0","0","0"
"2002172225","2024-02-19 20:00:00","5","Peak","0.1","0.01","0","0.01"
"2002173221","2024-02-19 20:00:00","15","Peak","0.176","0.112","0","0"
"2001767790","2024-02-19 19:55:00","5","Peak","0","0","0","0"
"2002172225","2024-02-19 19:55:00","5","Peak","0.1","0.01","0","0.02"
"2001767790","2024-02-19 19:50:00","5","Peak","0","0","0","0"
"2002172225","2024-02-19 19:50:00","5","Peak","0.08","0","0","0.01"
"2001767790","2024-02-19 19:45:00","5","Peak","0.01","0","0","0"
"2002172225","2024-02-19 19:45:00","5","Peak","0.08","0","0","0.02"
"2002173221","2024-02-19 19:45:00","15","Peak","0.176","0.112","0","0"
"2001767790","2024-02-19 19:40:00","5","Peak","0","0","0","0"
"2002172225","2024-02-19 19:40:00","5","Peak","0.09","0","0","0.02"
"2001767790","2024-02-19 19:35:00","5","Peak","0","0","0","0"
"2002172225","2024-02-19 19:35:00","5","Peak","0.08","0","0","0.02"
"2001767790","2024-02-19 19:30:00","5","Peak","0","0","0","0"
"2002172225","2024-02-19 19:30:00","5","Peak","0.08","0.01","0","0.02"
"2002173221","2024-02-19 19:30:00","15","Peak","0.128","0.072","0","0"
"2001767790","2024-02-19 19:25:00","5","Peak","0","0","0","0"
"2002172225","2024-02-19 19:25:00","5","Peak","0.09","0.01","0","0.01"
"2001767790","2024-02-19 19:20:00","5","Peak","0","0","0","0"
"2002172225","2024-02-19 19:20:00","5","Peak","0.09","0","0","0.02"
"2001767790","2024-02-19 19:15:00","5","Peak","0","0","0","0"
"2002172225","2024-02-19 19:15:00","5","Peak","0.09","0","0","0.01"
"2002173221","2024-02-19 19:15:00","15","Peak","0.424","0.288","0","0"
"2001767790","2024-02-19 19:10:00","5","Peak","0","0","0","0"
"2002172225","2024-02-19 19:10:00","5","Peak","0.08","0","0","0.02"
"2001767790","2024-02-19 19:05:00","5","Peak","0","0","0","0"
"2002172225","2024-02-19 19:05:00","5","Peak","0.09","0","0","0.02"
"2001767790","2024-02-19 19:00:00","5","Peak","0","0","0","0"
"2002172225","2024-02-19 19:00:00","5","Peak","0.1","0","0","0.01"
"2002173221","2024-02-19 19:00:00","15","Peak","0.656","0.424","0","0"
"2001767790","2024-02-19 18:55:00","5","Peak","0","0","0","0"
"2002172225","2024-02-19 18:55:00","5","Peak","0.11","0","0","0.02"
"2001767790","2024-02-19 18:50:00","5","Peak","0","0","0","0"
"2002172225","2024-02-19 18:50:00","5","Peak","0.12","0.02","0","0.02"
"2001767790","2024-02-19 18:45:00","5","Peak","0","0","0","0"
"2002172225","2024-02-19 18:45:00","5","Peak","0.11","0","0","0.01"
"2002173221","2024-02-19 18:45:00","15","Peak","0.64","0.432","0","0"
"2001767790","2024-02-19 18:40:00","5","Peak","0","0","0","0.01"
"2002172225","2024-02-19 18:40:00","5","Peak","0.1","0","0","0.02"
"2001767790","2024-02-19 18:35:00","5","Peak","0","0","0","0"
"2002172225","2024-02-19 18:35:00","5","Peak","0.11","0","0","0.01"
"2001767790","2024-02-19 18:30:00","5","Peak","0","0","0","0"
"2002172225","2024-02-19 18:30:00","5","Peak","0.11","0","0","0.02"
"2002173221","2024-02-19 18:30:00","15","Peak","0.408","0.28","0","0"
"2001767790","2024-02-19 18:25:00","5","Peak","0","0","0","0"
"2002172225","2024-02-19 18:25:00","5","Peak","0.12","0","0","0.01"
"2001767790","2024-02-19 18:20:00","5","Peak","0","0","0","0"
"2002172225","2024-02-19 18:20:00","5","Peak","0.12","0.02","0","0.02"
"2001767790","2024-02-19 18:15:00","5","Peak","0","0","0","0"
"2002172225","2024-02-19 18:15:00","5","Peak","0.15","0.03","0","0.01"
"2002173221","2024-02-19 18:15:00","15","Peak","0.648","0.44","0","0"
"2001767790","2024-02-19 18:10:00","5","Peak","0","0","0","0"
"2002172225","2024-02-19 18:10:00","5","Peak","1.08","0.93","0","0"
"2001767790","2024-02-19 18:05:00","5","Peak","0","0","0","0"
"2002172225","2024-02-19 18:05:00","5","Peak","2.62","2.39","0","0"
"2001767790","2024-02-19 18:00:00","5","Peak","0","0","0","0"
"2002172225","2024-02-19 18:00:00","5","Peak","1.22","1.07","0","0"
"2002173221","2024-02-19 18:00:00","15","Peak","0.52","0.36","0","0"
"2001767790","2024-02-19 17:55:00","5","Peak","0","0","0","0"
"2002172225","2024-02-19 17:55:00","5","Peak","2.27","1.8","0","0"
"2001767790","2024-02-19 17:50:00","5","Peak","0","0","0","0"
"2002172225","2024-02-19 17:50:00","5","Peak","2.73","1.84","0","0"
"2001767790","2024-02-19 17:45:00","5","Peak","0","0","0","0"
"2002172225","2024-02-19 17:45:00","5","Peak","3.03","2.45","0","0"
"2002173221","2024-02-19 17:45:00","15","Peak","0.592","0.416","0","0"
"2001767790","2024-02-19 17:40:00","5","Peak","0","0","0","0"
"2002172225","2024-02-19 17:40:00","5","Peak","3.58","2.56","0","0"
"2001767790","2024-02-19 17:35:00","5","Peak","0","0","0","0"
"2002172225","2024-02-19 17:35:00","5","Peak","3.64","2.59","0","0"
"2001767790","2024-02-19 17:30:00","5","Peak","0","0","0","0"
"2002172225","2024-02-19 17:30:00","5","Peak","3.39","2.74","0","0"
"2002173221","2024-02-19 17:30:00","15","Peak","0.384","0.264","0","0"
"2001767790","2024-02-19 17:25:00","5","Peak","0","0","0","0"
"2002172225","2024-02-19 17:25:00","5","Peak","3.82","2.81","0","0"
"2001767790","2024-02-19 17:20:00","5","Peak","0","0","0","0"
"2002172225","2024-02-19 17:20:00","5","Peak","3.69","2.78","0","0"
"2001767790","2024-02-19 17:15:00","5","Peak","0","0","0","0"
"2002172225","2024-02-19 17:15:00","5","Peak","3.86","2.6","0","0"
"2002173221","2024-02-19 17:15:00","15","Peak","0.272","0.184","0","0"
"2001767790","2024-02-19 17:10:00","5","Peak","0","0","0","0"
"2002172225","2024-02-19 17:10:00","5","Peak","3.81","2.72","0","0"
"2001767790","2024-02-19 17:05:00","5","Peak","0","0","0","0"
"2002172225","2024-02-19 17:05:00","5","Peak","3.85","2.67","0","0"
"2001767790","2024-02-19 17:00:00","5","Peak","0","0","0","0"
"2002172225","2024-02-19 17:00:00","5","Peak","3.84","2.57","0","0"
"2002173221","2024-02-19 17:00:00","15","Peak","0.224","0.144","0","0"
"2001767790","2024-02-19 16:55:00","5","Peak","0","0","0","0"
"2002172225","2024-02-19 16:55:00","5","Peak","4","2.72","0","0"
"2001767790","2024-02-19 16:50:00","5","Peak","0","0","0","0"
"2002172225","2024-02-19 16:50:00","5","Peak","4","2.63","0","0"
"2001767790","2024-02-19 16:45:00","5","Peak","0","0","0","0"
"2002172225","2024-02-19 16:45:00","5","Peak","3.98","2.65","0","0"
"2002173221","2024-02-19 16:45:00","15","Peak","0.272","0.192","0","0"
"2001767790","2024-02-19 16:40:00","5","Peak","0","0","0","0"
"2002172225","2024-02-19 16:40:00","5","Peak","4","2.65","0","0"
"2001767790","2024-02-19 16:35:00","5","Peak","0","0","0","0"
"2002172225","2024-02-19 16:35:00","5","Peak","4.11","2.79","0","0"
"2001767790","2024-02-19 16:30:00","5","Peak","0","0","0","0"
"2002172225","2024-02-19 16:30:00","5","Peak","3.99","2.64","0","0"
"2002173221","2024-02-19 16:30:00","15","Peak","0.24","0.16","0","0"
"2001767790","2024-02-19 16:25:00","5","Peak","0","0","0","0"
"2002172225","2024-02-19 16:25:00","5","Peak","4.03","2.64","0","0"
"2001767790","2024-02-19 16:20:00","5","Peak","0","0","0","0"
"2002172225","2024-02-19 16:20:00","5","Peak","3.94","2.63","0","0"
"2001767790","2024-02-19 16:15:00","5","Peak","0","0","0","0"
"2002172225","2024-02-19 16:15:00","5","Peak","3.95","2.64","0","0"
"2002173221","2024-02-19 16:15:00","15","Peak","0.32","0.216","0","0"
"2001767790","2024-02-19 16:10:00","5","Peak","0","0","0","0"
"2002172225","2024-02-19 16:10:00","5","Peak","4.08","2.73","0","0"
"2001767790","2024-02-19 16:05:00","5","Peak","0","0","0","0"
"2002172225","2024-02-19 16:05:00","5","Peak","3.15","2.02","0","0"
"2001767790","2024-02-19 16:00:00","5","Peak","0","0","0","0"
"2002172225","2024-02-19 16:00:00","5","Peak","2.96","1.81","0","0"
"2002173221","2024-02-19 16:00:00","15","Peak","0.36","0.256","0","0"
"2001767790","2024-02-19 15:55:00","5","Peak","0","0","0","0"
"2002172225","2024-02-19 15:55:00","5","Peak","3.94","2.67","0","0"
"2001767790","2024-02-19 15:50:00","5","Peak","0","0","0","0"
"2002172225","2024-02-19 15:50:00","5","Peak","3.95","2.67","0","0"
"2001767790","2024-02-19 15:45:00","5","Peak","0","0","0","0"
"2002172225","2024-02-19 15:45:00","5","Peak","3.22","2.2","0","0"
"2002173221","2024-02-19 15:45:00","15","Peak","0.16","0.104","0","0"
"2001767790","2024-02-19 15:40:00","5","Peak","0","0","0","0"
"2002172225","2024-02-19 15:40:00","5","Peak","1.49","0.63","0","0"
"2001767790","2024-02-19 15:35:00","5","Peak","0","0","0","0"
"2002172225","2024-02-19 15:35:00","5","Peak","1.17","0.36","0","0"
"2001767790","2024-02-19 15:30:00","5","Peak","0","0","0","0"
"2002172225","2024-02-19 15:30:00","5","Peak","1.2","0.35","0","0"
"2002173221","2024-02-19 15:30:00","15","Peak","0.128","0.08","0","0"
"2001767790","2024-02-19 15:25:00","5","Peak","0","0","0","0"
"2002172225","2024-02-19 15:25:00","5","Peak","1.02","0.27","0","0"
"2001767790","2024-02-19 15:20:00","5","Peak","0","0","0","0"
"2002172225","2024-02-19 15:20:00","5","Peak","1.04","0.27","0","0"
"2001767790","2024-02-19 15:15:00","5","Peak","0","0","0","0"
"2002172225","2024-02-19 15:15:00","5","Peak","1.06","0.28","0","0"
"2002173221","2024-02-19 15:15:00","15","Peak","0.176","0.12","0","0"
"2001767790","2024-02-19 15:10:00","5","Peak","0","0","0","0"
"2002172225","2024-02-19 15:10:00","5","Peak","1","0.27","0","0"
"2001767790","2024-02-19 15:05:00","5","Peak","0","0","0","0"
"2002172225","2024-02-19 15:05:00","5","Peak","0.68","0.31","0","0"
"2001767790","2024-02-19 15:00:00","5","Peak","0","0","0","0"
"2002172225","2024-02-19 15:00:00","5","Peak","0.08","0","0","0.02"
"2002173221","2024-02-19 15:00:00","15","Peak","0.456","0.32","0","0"
"2001767790","2024-02-19 14:55:00","5","Peak","0","0","0","0"
"2002172225","2024-02-19 14:55:00","5","Peak","0.07","0","0","0.02"
"2001767790","2024-02-19 14:50:00","5","Peak","0","0","0","0"
"2002172225","2024-02-19 14:50:00","5","Peak","0.08","0","0","0.02"
"2001767790","2024-02-19 14:45:00","5","Peak","0","0","0","0"
"2002172225","2024-02-19 14:45:00","5","Peak","0.08","0","0","0.02"
"2002173221","2024-02-19 14:45:00","15","Peak","0.304","0.208","0","0"
"2001767790","2024-02-19 14:40:00","5","Peak","0","0","0","0"
"2002172225","2024-02-19 14:40:00","5","Peak","0.09","0.02","0","0.02"
"2001767790","2024-02-19 14:35:00","5","Peak","0","0","0","0"
"2002172225","2024-02-19 14:35:00","5","Peak","0.08","0","0","0.02"
"2001767790","2024-02-19 14:30:00","5","Peak","0","0","0","0"
"2002172225","2024-02-19 14:30:00","5","Peak","0.08","0","0","0.01"
"2002173221","2024-02-19 14:30:00","15","Peak","0.336","0.24","0","0"
"2001767790","2024-02-19 14:25:00","5","Peak","0","0","0","0"
"2002172225","2024-02-19 14:25:00","5","Peak","0.09","0","0","0.02"
"2001767790","2024-02-19 14:20:00","5","Peak","0","0","0","0"
"2002172225","2024-02-19 14:20:00","5","Peak","1.23","0","0","0.02"
"2001767790","2024-02-19 14:15:00","5","Peak","0","0","0","0"
"2002172225","2024-02-19 14:15:00","5","Peak","0.08","0","0","0.02"
"2002173221","2024-02-19 14:15:00","15","Peak","0.4","0.288","0","0"
"2001767790","2024-02-19 14:10:00","5","Peak","0","0","0","0"
"2002172225","2024-02-19 14:10:00","5","Peak","0.08","0","0","0.02"
"2001767790","2024-02-19 14:05:00","5","Peak","0","0","0","0.01"
"2002172225","2024-02-19 14:05:00","5","Peak","0.08","0.01","0","0.02"
"2001767790","2024-02-19 14:00:00","5","Peak","0","0","0","0"
"2002172225","2024-02-19 14:00:00","5","Peak","0.08","0","0","0.02"
"2002173221","2024-02-19 14:00:00","15","Peak","0.432","0.312","0","0"
"2001767790","2024-02-19 13:55:00","5","Peak","0","0","0","0"
"2002172225","2024-02-19 13:55:00","5","Peak","0.07","0.01","0","0.01"
"2001767790","2024-02-19 13:50:00","5","Peak","0","0","0","0"
"2002172225","2024-02-19 13:50:00","5","Peak","0.08","0","0","0.02"
"2001767790","2024-02-19 13:45:00","5","Peak","0","0","0","0"
"2002172225","2024-02-19 13:45:00","5","Peak","0.07","0","0","0.02"
"2002173221","2024-02-19 13:45:00","15","Peak","0.136","0.088","0","0"
"2001767790","2024-02-19 13:40:00","5","Peak","0","0","0","0"
"2002172225","2024-02-19 13:40:00","5","Peak","0.08","0","0","0.02"
"2001767790","2024-02-19 13:35:00","5","Peak","0","0","0","0"
"2002172225","2024-02-19 13:35:00","5","Peak","0.09","0.01","0","0.02"
"2001767790","2024-02-19 13:30:00","5","Peak","0","0","0","0"
"2002172225","2024-02-19 13:30:00","5","Peak","0.07","0","0","0.01"
"2002173221","2024-02-19 13:30:00","15","Peak","0.136","0.088","0","0"
"2001767790","2024-02-19 13:25:00","5","Peak","0","0","0","0"
"2002172225","2024-02-19 13:25:00","5","Peak","0.08","0","0","0.02"
"2001767790","2024-02-19 13:20:00","5","Peak","0","0","0","0"
"2002172225","2024-02-19 13:20:00","5","Peak","0.08","0.01","0","0.02"
"2001767790","2024-02-19 13:15:00","5","Peak","0","0","0","0"
"2002172225","2024-02-19 13:15:00","5","Peak","0.08","0","0","0.02"
"2002173221","2024-02-19 13:15:00","15","Peak","0.128","0.08","0","0"
"2001767790","2024-02-19 13:10:00","5","Peak","0","0","0","0"
"2002172225","2024-02-19 13:10:00","5","Peak","0.07","0","0","0.02"
"2001767790","2024-02-19 13:05:00","5","Peak","0","0","0","0"
"2002172225","2024-02-19 13:05:00","5","Peak","0.09","0.02","0","0.01"
"2001767790","2024-02-19 13:00:00","5","Peak","0","0","0","0"
"2002172225","2024-02-19 13:00:00","5","Peak","0.13","0.01","0","0.01"
"2002173221","2024-02-19 13:00:00","15","Peak","0.128","0.088","0","0"
"2001767790","2024-02-19 12:55:00","5","Peak","0","0","0","0"
"2002172225","2024-02-19 12:55:00","5","Peak","0.13","0.01","0","0"
"2001767790","2024-02-19 12:50:00","5","Peak","0","0","0","0"
"2002172225","2024-02-19 12:50:00","5","Peak","0.09","0.01","0","0.01"
"2001767790","2024-02-19 12:45:00","5","Peak","0","0","0","0"
"2002172225","2024-02-19 12:45:00","5","Peak","0.12","0.01","0","0.01"
"2002173221","2024-02-19 12:45:00","15","Peak","0.168","0.104","0","0"
"2001767790","2024-02-19 12:40:00","5","Peak","0","0","0","0"
"2002172225","2024-02-19 12:40:00","5","Peak","0.17","0.01","0","0"
"2001767790","2024-02-19 12:35:00","5","Peak","0","0","0","0"
"2002172225","2024-02-19 12:35:00","5","Peak","0.21","0.05","0","0"
"2001767790","2024-02-19 12:30:00","5","Peak","0","0","0","0"
"2002172225","2024-02-19 12:30:00","5","Peak","1.43","0.05","0","0"
"2002173221","2024-02-19 12:30:00","15","Peak","0.136","0.088","0","0"
"2001767790","2024-02-19 12:25:00","5","Peak","0","0","0","0"
"2002172225","2024-02-19 12:25:00","5","Peak","1.47","0.04","0","0"
"2001767790","2024-02-19 12:20:00","5","Peak","0","0","0","0"
"2002172225","2024-02-19 12:20:00","5","Peak","1.43","0.02","0","0"
"2001767790","2024-02-19 12:15:00","5","Peak","0","0","0","0"
"2002172225","2024-02-19 12:15:00","5","Peak","1.39","0.01","0","0"
"2002173221","2024-02-19 12:15:00","15","Peak","0.2","0.136","0","0"
"2001767790","2024-02-19 12:10:00","5","Peak","0","0","0","0"
"2002172225","2024-02-19 12:10:00","5","Peak","1.4","0.01","0","0"
"2001767790","2024-02-19 12:05:00","5","Peak","0","0","0","0"
"2002172225","2024-02-19 12:05:00","5","Peak","1.35","0.01","0","0.02"
"2001767790","2024-02-19 12:00:00","5","Peak","0","0","0","0"
"2002172225","2024-02-19 12:00:00","5","Peak","1.37","0.01","0","0.01"
"2002173221","2024-02-19 12:00:00","15","Peak","0.528","0.384","0","0"
"2001767790","2024-02-19 11:55:00","5","Peak","0","0","0","0"
"2002172225","2024-02-19 11:55:00","5","Peak","1.35","0","0","0.02"
"2001767790","2024-02-19 11:50:00","5","Peak","0","0","0","0"
"2002172225","2024-02-19 11:50:00","5","Peak","1.34","0","0","0.02"
"2001767790","2024-02-19 11:45:00","5","Peak","0","0","0","0"
"2002172225","2024-02-19 11:45:00","5","Peak","1.34","0","0","0.02"
"2002173221","2024-02-19 11:45:00","15","Peak","0.68","0.464","0","0"
"2001767790","2024-02-19 11:40:00","5","Peak","0","0","0","0"
"2002172225","2024-02-19 11:40:00","5","Peak","1.35","0","0","0.02"
"2001767790","2024-02-19 11:35:00","5","Peak","0","0","0","0"
"2002172225","2024-02-19 11:35:00","5","Peak","1.34","0","0","0.02"
"2001767790","2024-02-19 11:30:00","5","Peak","0.01","0","0","0"
"2002172225","2024-02-19 11:30:00","5","Peak","1.35","0.01","0","0.02"
"2002173221","2024-02-19 11:30:00","15","Peak","0.672","0.464","0","0"
"2001767790","2024-02-19 11:25:00","5","Peak","0","0","0","0"
"2002172225","2024-02-19 11:25:00","5","Peak","1.34","0.01","0","0.02"
"2001767790","2024-02-19 11:20:00","5","Peak","0","0","0","0"
"2002172225","2024-02-19 11:20:00","5","Peak","2.95","1.7","0","0"
"2001767790","2024-02-19 11:15:00","5","Peak","0","0","0","0"
"2002172225","2024-02-19 11:15:00","5","Peak","1.35","0","0","0.02"
"2002173221","2024-02-19 11:15:00","15","Peak","0.68","0.456","0","0"
"2001767790","2024-02-19 11:10:00","5","Peak","0","0","0","0"
"2002172225","2024-02-19 11:10:00","5","Peak","1.34","0","0","0.02"
"2001767790","2024-02-19 11:05:00","5","Peak","0","0","0","0"
"2002172225","2024-02-19 11:05:00","5","Peak","1.33","0","0","0.02"
"2001767790","2024-02-19 11:00:00","5","Peak","0","0","0","0"
"2002172225","2024-02-19 11:00:00","5","Peak","1.34","0","0","0.02"
"2002173221","2024-02-19 11:00:00","15","Peak","0.672","0.464","0","0"
"2001767790","2024-02-19 10:55:00","5","Peak","0","0","0","0"
"2002172225","2024-02-19 10:55:00","5","Peak","1.35","0.01","0","0.02"
"2001767790","2024-02-19 10:50:00","5","Peak","0","0","0","0"
"2002172225","2024-02-19 10:50:00","5","Peak","1.33","0","0","0.02"
"2001767790","2024-02-19 10:45:00","5","Peak","0","0","0","0"
"2002172225","2024-02-19 10:45:00","5","Peak","1.34","0","0","0.02"
"2002173221","2024-02-19 10:45:00","15","Peak","0.68","0.456","0","0"
"2001767790","2024-02-19 10:40:00","5","Peak","0","0","0","0"
"2002172225","2024-02-19 10:40:00","5","Peak","1.33","0.01","0","0.02"
"2001767790","2024-02-19 10:35:00","5","Peak","0","0","0","0"
"2002172225","2024-02-19 10:35:00","5","Peak","1.34","0","0","0.02"
"2001767790","2024-02-19 10:30:00","5","Peak","0","0","0","0"
"2002172225","2024-02-19 10:30:00","5","Peak","1.33","0","0","0.02"
"2002173221","2024-02-19 10:30:00","15","Peak","0.208","0.144","0","0"
"2001767790","2024-02-19 10:25:00","5","Peak","0","0","0","0"`

Currently I'm executing three queries:

`SELECT elecdata.nmi as nmi, rate, nmilist.SiteName AS site, DATE(timestamp) AS datee, SUM(kWh_con) AS kwh FROM elecdata, nmilist WHERE elecdata.nmi = nmilist.nmi AND rate='Peak' AND DATE(timestamp) = (CURRENT_DATE() - 1) GROUP BY elecdata.nmi`

`SELECT elecdata.nmi as nmi, rate, nmilist.SiteName AS site, DATE(timestamp) AS datee, SUM(kWh_con) AS kwh FROM elecdata, nmilist WHERE elecdata.nmi = nmilist.nmi AND rate='Off-Peak' AND DATE(timestamp) = (CURRENT_DATE() - 1) GROUP BY elecdata.nmi`

`SELECT elecdata.nmi as nmi, nmilist.SiteName AS site, DATE(timestamp) AS datee, SUM(kWh_con) AS kwh FROM elecdata, nmilist WHERE elecdata.nmi = nmilist.nmi AND DATE(timestamp) = (CURRENT_DATE() - 1) GROUP BY elecdata.nmi`

To produce the following output which contains the information, just hard to read...

2001767790 Pivot 2    rate: Peak kwh: 1

2002172225 Dairy    rate: Peak kwh: 181

2002173221 Pivot 1    rate: Peak kwh: 20

2001767790 Pivot 2    rate: Off-Peak kwh: 637

2002172225 Dairy    rate: Off-Peak kwh: 208

2002173221 Pivot 1    rate: Off-Peak kwh: 816

2001767790 Pivot 2 Date : 2024-02-19 kwh: 639

2002172225 Dairy Date : 2024-02-19 kwh: 389

2002173221 Pivot 1 Date : 2024-02-19 kwh: 836

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can combine your three queries using conditional aggregation:

```sql
SELECT
    elecdata.nmi AS NMI,
    nmilist.SiteName AS SiteName,
    DATE(timestamp) AS Date,
    SUM(IF(rate='Off-Peak', kWh_con, 0)) AS `OffPeak Use`,
    SUM(IF(rate='Peak', kWh_con, 0)) AS `Peak Use`,
    SUM(kWh_con) AS Total
FROM elecdata
JOIN nmilist ON elecdata.nmi = nmilist.nmi
WHERE timestamp >= (CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 1 DAY)
AND timestamp < CURRENT_DATE
GROUP BY elecdata.nmi, Date;
```

For the data in your question this outputs:

| NMI | SiteName | Date | OffPeak Use | Peak Use | Total |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2001767790 | Pivot 2 | 2024-02-19 | 128.460 | 0.020 | 128.480 |
| 2002172225 | Dairy | 2024-02-19 | 33.960 | 156.770 | 190.730 |
| 2002173221 | Pivot 1 | 2024-02-19 | 164.224 | 15.280 | 179.504 |

Here's a [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/Wgx9XueN).

Comment: @tbru note that this answer changes your long-deprecated comma join syntax to modern explicit JOIN ON, and does timestamp comparisons in a way that allows an index on timestamp to be used, which `DATE(timestamp) =` does not.

Comment: currently sorts by nmi, I would add `ORDER BY SiteName, Date`